# Convert bytearray to bytes-like object

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

In Python 3 I'm getting error `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'bytearray'`

I have a bytearray, which looks like this:

```py
print(my_ba)     # bytearray(b'}\x0e\x15/ow4|-')
```

If I enter this in the console it works:

```
>>> print(base58.b58encode(b'}\x0e\x15/ow4|-'))
2bKmhuGiGP7t8
```

But this gives an error, and I can't find out how to get the b'' string from the bytearray:

```
>>> print(base58.b58encode(my_ba))
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'bytearray'
```

I'm sure it's obvious, but how do I convert the bytearray to a string with a `b` prefix?

Comment: `print(base58.b58encode(bytes(my_ba))` - just convert it

Comment: A bytearray *is* a bytes-like object, but the library you're using has an unnecessarily restrictive implementation and a misleading error message.

Comment: @user2357112, incidentally i ran into the same bytes parameter restriction within the stdlib `zlib.decompress` method

Answer (score 66, accepted):

As Coldspeed put it in the comments, just pass a bytearray to a `bytes` call:

`bytes(my_ba)`

Answer (score 2):

Concatenation between bytes and bytearray takes the type of the first item, so concatenating a bytearray to an empty byte string also converts it into bytes.

```py
my_ba = bytearray(b'}\x0e\x15/ow4|-')
my_ba = b"" + my_ba
print(type(my_ba))    # <class 'bytes'>
```

---

With that being said, this error probably doesn't show up in the recent versions of whatever library you're using because bytearray is a bytes-like type. For example, base58 accepts bytearray as is [since version 1.0.3.](https://github.com/keis/base58/commit/986319f966a2c86ac07c83e02032a7c96fa3bf73).

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug.

It [was fixed](https://github.com/keis/base58/commit/986319f966a2c86ac07c83e02032a7c96fa3bf73) in version 2.0.0 of base58, released in January 2020.

---

And of course, as previously noted, the workaround you can apply when this happens in other situations is just "casting" to bytes:

```py
buggy_function(bytes(my_byteslike))
```

**Note:** this has the overhead of copying all the data, when the data isn't already exactly the `bytes` type